# mstest how to prevent custom log file from being DELETED (and prevent .trx from being deleted too)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest

In a Micorosoft MSTest, I am creating a custom log file (.xlsx) dynamically in  unit tests in `ClassInitialize` and closing it in `ClassCleanup`. It gets created and populated but then when the tests have finished running, the log file in the out directory is somehow getting deleted.

Any ideas on how to prevent this log file and other files in the `TestResults/Out directory` from being deleted?

example location:

> C:\selenium\SelenMSTest4\TestResult\Deploy_ZZZ2013-01-09 10_50_03\Out

Microsoft MSTest 2012 and Selenium WebDriver are being used.  The test is being run from Visual Studio 2012 by selecting `Test--> Debug-->All Tests`

Comment: Are you sure that there is nothing wrong with your code? It is better not to handle logging by your own. Use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or a similar library for logging.

Comment: the log file is created fine.  Even the Microsoft Logfile is being deleted.

Comment: You are using mstest via the commandline?

Answer (score 2):

Creating a .runsettings file and setting "DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete" to false fixed the problem but then caused  deploymentitem not being found (more research needed on this complicated setup)

.runsettings addition:

```
<RunSettings> 
<MSTest>  
    <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>False</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>
</MSTest>
</RunSettings>
```

Comment: There is a reference for additional MSTest specific settings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx. Look for section "MSTest Run Settings"